# Android ViewGroup ticker

Tags: android, animation, viewgroup, ticker

I am developing an Android component that has the same functionality as a news Ticker. It's a *ViewGroup* that takes an array of *Views* and animate them to create the effect of a Ticker.

I have implemented the *onMeasure* and *onLayout* methods, and I have a timer that calls a method every X time to refresh the position of every *View*. It basically moves the position of every child by 5 pixels lets say.

Everything is working great so far, but the problem is that a few seconds after the *Views* start moving, they start to overlap on each others, as if some of them are going faster than others. I am moving all the *Views* with the same amount of pixels so they should be moving at the same speed. This problem only occurs on some devices (like the Galaxy SIII) and just works fine on others.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: you should be moving all the views at the same time, and you probably use different threads/times/asynctasks/whatever

Comment: also you could move only the parent...