# How to implement tickers in android for stocks and news?

Tags: android

How to implement an Android ticker for stocks/news. My requirement is to implement it like the one in image for [NASDAQ](http://www.nasdaq.com/) -

[image]

There are apps in market doing this so it is possible. [Nearest possible question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162888/android-viewgroup-ticker) failed to provide any relief. Sample Code for achieving this functionalty will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an view which is always visible and always on top of all the views, then have a look at the `SystemOverlay` in android. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android) also has some helpful information..

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735394/simple-android-scrolling-text-ticker) to create `TextView` with ticker like support and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332924/textview-marquee-not-working) for sample code...

Comment: Can you provide something more specific about tickers only. Thanks!

Comment: An system overlay can have any view.. So create your ticker view and add using system overlay...